# How to use createPortal in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-dom, react-portal

I want a component to be shared across multiple components, but without stop being reactive. I have tried this:

```
const ShareCtx = createContext({});

const useShare = () => useContext(ShareCtx);

const ShareProvider = ({children}) => {

  const [portalComponent, setPortalComponent] = useState(null);

  return <ShareCtx.Provider value={{portalComponent, setPortalComponent}}>
    {children}
  </ShareCtx.Provider>
}

const HigherInHierarchy = ({children}) => {

  const {portalComponent} = useShare();

  return <div>
    <p>Higher in hierarchy</p>
    {portalComponent}
    {children}
  </div>
}

const LowerInHierarchy = ({children}) => {

  const {portalComponent, setPortalComponent} = useShare();

  const [value, setValue] = useState('middle');

  const x = useMemo(() => {
    return <input
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
  }, [value])

  useEffect(() => {
    setPortalComponent(x);
  }, [])

  return <div>
    <p>Lower in hierarchy</p>
    {x}
  </div>
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <ShareProvider>
      <HigherInHierarchy>
        <LowerInHierarchy />
      </HigherInHierarchy>
    </ShareProvider>
  );
}
```

The lower order component, creates an `x` component and renders it. Also, it assigns it to the `ShareCtx`. The problem I am facing is that although the `{x}` part works fine inside the render method of `LowerInHierarchy`, the same does not apply for `{portalComponent}` inside the render method of `HigherInHierarchy` component.

Should I use `createPortal` for this or something else ?

What I am trying to solve is to have 1) a local state defined in some component, 2) a functional component that gets passed this local state as props, 3) this component to be rendered in any other place.